# javascript to check a private api feed for updates/refresh

Tags: javascript, json

So i am accessing a live feed and through a javascript api which is working fine, but how would I check the feed for updates/refresh? Below is the code that I am using to get the feed, right now, just one at a time. I'm sure there is a very simple solution to get updates. there are a set number of id's returned so the json would update existing results.

```
var api = GeotabApi(function (authenticateCallback) {

        authenticateCallback('server', 'database', 'userName', 'password', function(err) {
            console.error(err);
        });

    }, {
        // Overrides for default options
        rememberMe: false
    });


api.call('Get', {
    typeName: 'Device',
    resultsLimit: 1
}, function (result) {
    if (result) {
        console.log(result);
    }
}, function (err) {
    console.error(err);
});
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you call the api in timer? Maybe I am missing something... Here is some reading on timers https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Timers

Comment: hmm, so right now it's writing to the console until I get it working and eventually i'll be parsing out the json and loading the XY on a leaflet map. Right now though, the api.call doesn't update.  I'm trying to find the code that will cause the get to refresh and get the updated feed. what would a code sample to get this thing refreshed look like?

Comment: are you going to pass in the same parameters for every update (same as you have now) API call and do the same thing with the output?

Comment: yes, i mean for the time being, i'm just trying to get a live stream of continuous data, then later I can worry about passing different parameters. unfortunately, i'm a novice at js.

Comment: I posted a code example for you below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your api.call code into a function and then call it repeatedly through the use of a timer. [SetInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) will work nicely here - it calls the function every x ms. Here is an example

```
var delay = 10 * 1000; // 10 seconds

// call api every x seconds to get an update
var intervalID = setInterval(callAPI, delay);

function callAPI() {
  api.call('Get', {
    typeName: 'Device',
    resultsLimit: 1
  }, function(result) {
    if (result) {
      console.log(result);
    }
  }, function(err) {
    console.error(err);
  });
}

// you can cancel the interval at any time using 
// clearInterval(intervalID);
```